# How can I make the default value of an argument depend on another argument (in Python)?

Tags: python, function, arguments

For instance, I want:

```
def func(n=5.0,delta=n/10):
```

If the user has specified a delta, use it. If not, use a value that depends on n. Is this possible?

Comment: Python doesn't support doing this directly in the arglist, unlike (say) R. The Python solution is typically to default to `None` (`/np.nan/ np.NINF/np.PINF/`etc.) and then have the function body compute the correct default.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The language doesn't support such syntax.

The usual workaround for these situations(*) is to use a default value which is not a valid input.

```
def func(n=5.0, delta=None):
     if delta is None:
         delta = n/10
```

(*) Similar problems arise when the default value is mutable.

Comment: Since this is canonical, you want to illustrate why Python messes up when the default value is mutable.

Comment: `delta = delta if delta != None else n/10` for a one-liner

Comment: *For non falsy values*, I find  `delta = delta or n/10` to be more pleasing

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it in the function definition line itself, you need to do it in the body of the function:

```
def func(n=5.0,delta=None):
    if delta is None:
        delta = n/10
```

Answer (score 3):

These answers will work in some cases, but if your dependent argument (delta) is a list or any iterable data type, the line

```
    if delta is None:
```

will throw the error

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

If your dependent argument is a `dataframe`, `list`, `Series`, etc, the following lines of code will work better. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14749328/how-to-check-whether-optional-function-parameter-is-set) post for the idea / more details.

```
    def f(n, delta = None):
        if delta is f.__defaults__[0]:
            delta = n/10
```

Comment: upvoted. python is always harder to use than it could be.  and i'm ten years into the language.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
def func(n=5.0, delta=None):
    if delta is None:
        delta = n / 10
    ...
```