# Using given parameter as a default value for another paramater in Python

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I want to have the following heading where the default value of a parameter depends on another parameter:

```
def function2(x,l=0,r=len(x)-1)
```

This obviously returns an error. Is there any way to go around this?

Thank you

Comment: Why dont you define `r` inside `function2`?

Comment: But that would override those cases where `r` is not equal to `len(x)-1`, right?

Comment: @zest16 You can play around with the parameter inside the function. 
`def function2(x, l, r): r = len(x)-1 ...

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21804615/how-can-i-make-the-default-value-of-an-argument-depend-on-another-argument-in-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This workaround maybe can help:

```
def function2(x, l=0, r=None):
    if r is None:
        r = len(x) - 1
    ...
```

This will set `r` to `len(x) - 1` only when `r` is not set, i.e:

```
function2(x='hi', l=0)  # r will take value len(x) - 1
function2(x='hi', l=0, r=5)  # r will take value 5
```

Comment: Yes, quite simple actually, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this solution will completely help you.

If a variable depends on another input variable it might be interesting to do something like:

```py
def function2(x,l=0):
     r = len(x) - 1
     ...
```

Comment: OP still wants `r` to be a parameter of the function, but with a default value of `len(x) - 1`.