# Can I check if a value was supplied by the default or by the user?

Tags: python, argparse

Is there a way, when using `argparse`, to tell whether a field has a value because the user specified it or because it was not specified and got the default value? *Note:* I would also like to consider the case where the user explicitly specifies the default value.

I would like to use `argparse` to process command line arguments, and I would like to use `formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter` to display what the default value will be for fields that are not specified.  In addition, I would like to read values from a config file.

If the user specifies a value on the command line, I would like to make sure I use that value (even if that value matches the default, but was explicitly stated).  If the user did not specify a value, but one is found in the config file, I would like to use that.  If the user did not specify one on the command line, and there is not a value in the config file, then I would like to use the default value that was displayed in the usage statement above.

So, I might set up the parse like

```
parser = parser = argparse.ArgumentParser( description="""Tool with many ways to get values""", formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter )
parser.add_argument( '-p', '--path', help="The path to a file to read", default="data.csv" )
parser.add_argument( '-c', '--conf', help="The config file to use", default="config.txt" )
```

and perhaps there are many other parameters.

Now, I would like to also read a config file, which may include a value

```
data_path = data2.csv
```

So if the user specifies a `-p` on the command line, I would like to read that file; if they do not and I use that config file, I would like to read `data2.csv`; and if I use a config file that does not define `data_path` and they do not specify `-p`, I would like to use the default `data.csv`.

The main complicating case for me would be if the user specifies `-p data.csv` then it will have the value of the default value, but should take precedence over the config file.

Does `argparse` or another similar tool have a way to tell if the parameter was set by falling through to the default or was explicitly set by the user?

Comment: The parser maintains a `seen_actions` set to check, at the end, for required arguments.  But that isn't available to you.

Comment: Related: [How to check whether optional function parameter is set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14749328/3357935)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't specify a default value if it's just complicating things:

```
parser.add_argument('-p', '--path', 
                    help="The path to a file to read")
```

And then later on in your code:

```
if args.path:
    # user specify a value for path
    # using -p
    pass
elif cfg.path:
    # user provided a path in the configuration value
    args.path = cfg.path
else:
    # no value was specified, use some sort of default value
    args.path = DEFAULT_PATH
```

Or, more compactly:

```
args.path = next(val for val in 
                 [args.path, cfg.path, DEFAULT_PATH]
                 if val is not None)
```

This assumes that `cfg.path` will be `None` if no path was specified in the config file.  So if `cfg` is actually a dictionary, `cfg.get('path')` would do the right thing.

And just for kicks, here's a terrible idea that can tell the
difference between using a default value and explicit specifying a
value that is the same as the default:

```
import argparse

class Default(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

DEFAULT_PATH = Default('/some/path')

def parse_args():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument('--path', '-p',
                   default=DEFAULT_PATH)
    return p.parse_args()

def main():
    args = parse_args()

    if args.path is DEFAULT_PATH:
        print 'USING DEFAULT'
    else:
        print 'USING EXPLICIT'

    print args.path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that I don't actually think this is a good idea.

Comment: The only reason I was shying away from that and hoping there was another way to tell is for formatting the usage statement.  I can manually include the default in the `help` for the parameter, but it could be a pain making sure it always looks like other default values.

Comment: I've made a couple of updates, one possibly useful and one you should probably avoid.

Comment: Was going to say the same thing, without all the details, nice answer!

Comment: A nice thing about `None` is that the user cannot supply it.

Comment: ...which gets you the first solution presented in this answer.

Comment: Why Default type is a bad idea? IMHO it works nicely and checking `if type(args.path) is Default: ...` is a nice and readable solution. Even is you have multiple arguments... What are the issues with it?

Comment: Because in almost all cases I don't think it's necessary to differentiate between "user did not provide an argument" and "user provided an argument that matches the default value".